# Difficulty tracking grand total of combinations when iterating a combinatorics problem along an index

Tags: combinatorics

I have a scalar, $x_i$ for $i=1,\dots, N$.

This scalar can be constructed using all other or some other $a_j$'s where $\boldsymbol{a}$ is an $N \times 1$ vector.  So in the end I will have an $N \times 1$ vector $\boldsymbol{x} = (x_1,\dots,x_N)'$

Suppose $i=1$ for ease of notation, then $x_1$ can be constructed using all $N-1$ $a_j$'s or any combination thereof so long as the $a_1$ itself is omitted in $x_1$'s construction.

So, for x_1, I conclude there are $N-1$ objects to choose from and we choose $N-j$ for $j=1,\dots,N-1$ or: $\binom{N-1}{N-j} \,\,\, j=1,\dots,N-1$, possible combinations in constructing $x_1$.

That is just for $i=1$, but I'm trying to compute the total number of combinations for $i=1,\dots N$. More specifically, I'm having trouble notationally tracking, as compactly as possible, the total number of combinations for $i=1,\dots, N$.  Any suggestions?

Comment: How are you getting a scalar $x_i$ from the vector $a_j$ (or as you're implying, a nonempty(?) set of vectors)? Additionally, unless you aren't allowed to repeat $a_j$, then none of the $x_i$s interfere and the combinations just multiply. Otherwise, you're dealing with a partition problem in putting the however many $a$s into the buckets of $x$s.

Comment: That is a good point, I get a scalar via a dot product using some other vector, not mentioned in the question. Apologies for any confusion. That other vector not mentioned, say $\boldsymbol{y}$, is $(N-j) \times 1$ so that it is conformable with how many $a_j$'s I select. The $a_j$'s can not be repeated in construction of $x_i$, but they can be reused in $x_k$'s construction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you getting a scalar $x_i$ from these vector $a_j$s? You seem to also be getting them from a nonempty(?) set of vectors?

Additionally, unless you aren't allowed to repeat $a_j$s (between different $x$s), then none of the $x_i$s interfere and the combinations just multiply. At this point, you can select any subset of the $a_j$ except $a_i$, so it's just $2^{M-1}$ for $M$ total $a$s. If the empty set is disallowed, subtract one. Total combinations is just $2^{N(M-1)}$ (or $\left(2^{M-1}-1\right)^N$).

If you're not allowed to repeat $a_j$s, then this is a partition problem of putting the $a$s into the buckets of $x$s. With no actual restriction on the size of the buckets, this is easy: just treat each $a_j$ as being put into exactly one (or none) of the buckets. There are $N$ choices (add one if $a_j$ need not be used). This results in $N^M$ (or $\left(N+1\right)^M$). For nonempty $x$s not allowed, do inclusion-exclusion.

Comment: In this problem $M=N-1$, say we fix $N=3$. Then $2^{N(N-1-1)}=2^{N(N-2)}=2^{3(1)}=8$ total combinations. But for $i=1$, I can make $x_1$ using $a_2, a_3$ or $a_2$ or $a_3$. For $i=2$ I can make $x_2$ using  $a_1, a_3$ or $a_1$ or $a_3$ and for $i=3$ I can make $x_3$ using $a_1, a_2$ or $a_1$ or $a_2$ for a total of 9 total combinations. This I believe corresponds to $N^M$

Comment: What you're missing is that you can pick any of the three choices for $x_1$, then **independently** pick between the three choices for $x_2$, and again for $x_3$. Next, you're stated $M$ incorrectly, since there are *three* $a_i$s, so $M=N$. Next, as I said, you're disallowing the empty set so subtract one, and the actual count is $(2^{M-1}-1)^N=3^3=27$

Comment: You do not add independent choices. A **single** choice for constructing one of your vectors $\boldsymbol{x}$ is (use $a_2$ for $x_1$, AND use $a_1+a_3$ for $x_2$, AND use $a_2$ for $x_3$)

Comment: But I mentioned in the question that "1  can be constructed using all −1 's or any combination thereof so long as the 1 itself is omitted in 1's construction" so I don't see why you state when $N=3$,  "we can pick any of the three choices"

Comment: I already subtracted one for that. We're using $M-1$. $M$ counts the total number of $a_j$s in existence. The three choices are "nonempty subsets of a set of size $M-1=2$, namely $\{a_2,a_3\}$"

Comment: I understand now, thank you